# Exporting and importing "schema" from/to Oracle 12.1 on AWS RDS

Tags: oracle, import, export, amazon-rds, database-backups

I have my database on Oracle @ AWS RDS (v12.1). I want to backup a schema in a flat file and import it back to the database when required. The obvious choice is to use expdp/impdp commands however, Oracle version 12.1 require a full Oracle server setup to use these. I don't have a full Oracle server to use. Version 12.2 does provide the tools as independent installers but AWS RDS does not support v12.2. I wish to backup and restore only a specific schema and not the full database. 
  The approach I can think of is to write a PL/SQL script that will loop through the DDL, data, constraints and other artifacts and dump it to a flat file and another PL/SQL script which would import the contents from the flat file to the database. 
  Does anyone have any pointers to do this in an efficient way ?

Comment: what privileges have your os user? you don't need a full access you just need a directory where oracle is able to write and start the expdp command with a user with EXP_FULL_DATABASE privilege.

Comment: I would still need to install Oracle on a separate box. I dont have a full oracle db installation

Comment: maybe this can help: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/4173109646282306

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SQL Developer" to connect to the specified DB and extract complete schema DDL using "Database Export"(Tools > Database Export) functionality. At a later time you can just execute this extracted DDL script and recreate the schema.

[image: Graphic description]

Comment: It exports the complete database, I am looking for exporting a particular user schema

Comment: You should be able to restrict it to a particular schema.

Comment: Specify Objects > Schema drop down menu